# Python API to get access token and then fetch data

Tags: python, json, webapi, rest

I am a beginner with python API. My requirement is to extract data from a third party. Sharing the main parts of the documentation shared with me, also the token gets expired after 24hrs.
Please help me with the python code for this.(had tried something simple with requests, but to no luck.)

user id and password shared - ID: trial PWD: aaw3r5lL

**Login request:**

Function:          Generate Token ID and return based on ID / PWD  |
Method:            POST|
URL:               [https://api.Asw.com/api/auth[.json/.xml]|](https://api.Asw.com/api/auth%5B.json/.xml%5D%7C)
Parameter :        uid  Username / ID (Required)|
,password Password (Required)|
Request Header :     None |
Return Value :      TokenID in JSON / XML format |
Response Header :   None |

**Data Request:**

Function:           Get vessel track / pinpoint weather data in JSON / XML format|
Method :            POST|
URL  :              https://api.Asw.com/api/v1/hires-weather-on-track. [json/xml]|
Parameter :         point Point list in JSON format (Required)|
,       ● Maximum 100 Points|
Parameter Type  :   Request body parameters|
Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded|
Request Header :    Authorization "AswWebApi " + Token ID |
Response Header :   - |
Return Value :      JSON / XML |

Thank you!